# Who was the first DC/Marvel Comic book Hero character with magic based powers?

Tags: marvel, dc, magic

Some comic book heros have mutant powers, alien abilities, and/or super cool gadgets. Who was the first DC/Marvel comic book Hero character with magic based powers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**First major user of magick in the DC Universe was [Doctor Occult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Occult) (More Fun Comics #6, 1935).**

[image: Dr. Occult]

> The character first appeared in New Fun Comics #6 in 1935. He was a supernatural detective, whose detecting style was very much in the style of Sam Spade, only with supernatural abilities. He was assisted by his butler Jenkins in one adventure. His girlfriend/partner called Rose Psychic appeared in his first adventure and then returned again later in the series.
>
> He also appeared in Centaur Publications' The Comics Magazine #1 under the name "Dr. Mystic". This was the same character because his story, "The Koth and the Seven", began in The Comics Magazine and continued in DC's More Fun Comics #14-17 (issues also designated as vol. 2, #2-5). In this story, he travels to a mystic realm where he flies and wears a cape, making him the first caped comic book superhero. This story also introduced the Seven, a group of mystics who would later be retconned into having raised Richard Occult and Rose Psychic. Doctor Occult made his last original appearance in More Fun Comics #32 in 1938.
>
> He later appeared in Crisis on Infinite Earths (1986), The Books of Magic (1991), Vertigo Visions: Dr. Occult (June 1994), and The Trenchcoat Brigade (1999).

[image: First black and white pages of Dr Occult.]

Marvel's first well known magic user is the famous Dr. Stephen Strange who debuted in Strange Tales #110 (July 1963). The good Doctor would herald in an entire age of new magical menaces, visionary worlds and long-lived memes of the Marvel Universe. These would include: The Dark Dimension and its terrifying master, the [Dread Dormammu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormammu), [Nightmare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightmare_%28Marvel_Comics%29) and the Nightmare Realm, The Undying Ones, [Baron Mordo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baron_Mordo), [The Enchantress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enchantress_%28Marvel_Comics%29) and the Doctor's one great love, [Clea](http://marvel.com/universe/Clea).

[image: First appearance of Doctor Strange]

> The character, created by writer-artist Steve Ditko with dialogue by editor-writer Stan Lee, debuted in Strange Tales #110 (July 1963), a "split book" shared with fellow Marvel character the Human Torch until issue #134 (July 1965), and then super-spy Nick Fury until issue #168 (May 1968). Strange appeared in issues #110-111 and #114 before the character's eight-page origin story appeared in #115 (Dec. 1963).

Comment: Doctor Occult? Nonsense... that's Dick Tracy.